# Error while importing text files using read.table: EOF within quoted string

Tags: r, eof, read.table, csv

I tried to import a text file company.txt in r using read.table and using tab as a delimiter. But everytime it says eof within quoted string. I have tried fill=true , quote = "\"'" but of no use. Here is what I entered:

```
> company <- read.table("company.txt",header=TRUE,sep = "\t",quote = "\"'",fill = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE, )
Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

Comment: It is not an error, it is a warning.

Answer (score 0):

your quote argument seems odd to me. Why dont you use this:

```
quote="'"
```

(If ' is your quote)
You dont need to escape it. Only if you use " as quote, then it would be:

```
quote="\""
```

But nevertheless it would be helpful if you could upload your text file or a least a snippet of it